# API URL Works in browser but not in REST. It gives "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

API request works in browser and it returns a JSON. But whe I call it in web api it gives "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)." error. Other get requests works fine except this.

```
string url = "https://..../search.json?query=abc:123";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{                 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(content);
}
```

Comment: The URL is empty.  How are you successfully requesting an empty URL in your browser?  I would expect this code to throw an exception on `new Uri(url)`.

Comment: Run Fiddler or other proxy/capture software and compare requests from  the browsers & your code looking for differences.

Comment: why is the variable `url` empty ?

Comment: `url` is there and I forgot to include it in the question. It is added.

Comment: Try with a properly escaped querystring  -`?query=abc%3A123`

Comment: @AlexK. I have tried it. still gives the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Set `url` variable and remove BaseAddress. When you execute `GetStringAsync(url)`, the `HttpClient` concatenate baseAddress and url passed in the parameter of `GetStringAsync`

```
string url = ""; //Set url here

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{                
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(content);
}
```

Comment: url is there and updated the question. can you elaborate more?

Comment: Remove client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url); line, When you execute the method client.GetStringAsync, the HttpClient concatenate BaseAddress with url passed in parameter of this method.

Comment: Sorry, `client.BaseAddress` is added lately for testing purpose it gives the same  error without client.BaseAddress.

Comment: Try to inspect headers sent with the browser when you access this URL. Add all headers to you HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'Accept-Language' header as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554810/c-sharp-httpclient-sendasync-always-returns-404-but-url-works-in-browser) solution posted in one another Stackoverflow thread